# apache reverse proxy - how to hide internal network

Tags: apache, reverse, reverse-proxy

my scenario is this: I have a machine with Apache 2.2 configured as reverse proxy
and another machine on which there is Apache Tomcat7 listening on port 8080.

My objective is to make internet users accessing a resource "am" (deployed on Tomcat) 
WITHOUT using IP address of the Tomcat machine but only contacting the reverse proxy.

So far I set httpd.conf of the reverse proxy:

ProxyPass       /am     http://tomcat_server.com:8080/am
ProxyPassReverse    /am http://tomcat_server.com:8080/am

But the problem is that the reverse proxy tells the users to contact tomcat_server
but of course tomcat_server is a private IP and cannot be accessed by internet users.

Comment: How does it "tell the user"? HTML? Redirect?

Answer (score 1):

In your **Tomcat server.xml** config file,

edit the http *Connector* to include attributes: **proxyPort**, **proxyName** - such that it resembles:

```
<Connector
 port="8080"
 protocol="HTTP/1.1"
 connectionTimeout="20000"
 redirectPort="8443"
 proxyPort="80"
 proxyName="url.domain.clients.use.for.your.webapp"
 />
```

- proxyPort="80"  -- makes Tomcat return data to your Apache proxy
- **proxyName="url.domain.clients.use.for.your.webapp"** -- makes Tomcat return the url to Apache proxy that your user clients should process, instead of tomcat_server.com which they can't access

---

Here are some older Tomcat docs that mention it:

*proxyName*

> If this Connector is being used in a proxy configuration, configure
>   this attribute to specify the server name to be returned for calls to
>   request.getServerName(). See Proxy Support for more information.

*Proxy Support*

> The proxyName and proxyPort attributes can be used when Tomcat is run
>   behind a proxy server. These attributes modify the values returned to
>   web applications that call the request.getServerName() and
>   request.getServerPort() methods, which are often used to construct
>   absolute URLs for redirects. Without configuring these attributes, the
>   values returned would reflect the server name and port on which the
>   connection from the proxy server was received, rather than the server
>   name and port to whom the client directed the original request.

---

I worked through a similar need, with having Tomcat listen only on its localhost:

[How can Tomcat 9 Connector listening 127.0.0.1 reverse proxy to Win. Apache 2.4 with private ServerName](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50003835/how-can-tomcat-9-connector-listening-127-0-0-1-reverse-proxy-to-win-apache-2-4)

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is references to the origin server in HTML, check out mod_proxy_html or mod_substitute.